# PHP freeze: how to loop connected to 2 MySQL databases

Tags: php, mysql, loops, freeze

How to perform that loop:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    collectData($row['NAME']);
}
```

To not freeze my PHP after 30 seconds?

I think it can be done by taking whole Database into array or *.temp file to work with it, not to connect everytime I want to input/output something. But I have problems with files and arrays, so thats why I am asking: whats the better/best way to do it fast and painless?

```
<?php

//fiveMin - Database that data is taken form
//HighCharts - Database that data is transferred to

$fiveMin=mysql_connect($fiveMin_host,$fiveMin_user,$fiveMin_pass);
mysql_select_db($fiveMin_db,$fiveMin) or die (mysql_error());               

$query="SELECT * FROM BetterShopItemStock";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    collectData($row['NAME']);
}

function collectData($itemID) {

    global $fiveMin_host, $fiveMin_user, $fiveMin_pass, $fiveMin_db, $week_host, $week_user, $week_pass, $week_db;  

    $fiveMin=mysql_connect($fiveMin_host,$fiveMin_user,$fiveMin_pass); //Load and store data from fiveMin Database
    mysql_select_db($fiveMin_db,$fiveMin) or die (mysql_error());
    $function_Query="SELECT AMT FROM BetterShopItemStock WHERE NAME = '$itemID'";
    $function_Ask = mysql_query($function_Query);
    $function_Result = mysql_fetch_row($function_Ask, 0);
    $dataReadyToImport = "," . $function_Result[0];
    @mysql_close($fiveMin);

    $HighCharts=mysql_connect($week_host,$week_user,$week_pass); //Save stored data to weekly Database
    mysql_select_db($week_db,$HighCharts) or die (mysql_error());
    $function_Query="SELECT AMT FROM BetterShopItemStock WHERE NAME = '$itemID'";
    $function_Ask = mysql_query($function_Query);
    $function_Result = mysql_fetch_row($function_Ask, 0);
    $storedData = $function_Result[0];
    $dataReadyToImport = $storedData . $dataReadyToImport;
    mysql_query("UPDATE BetterShopItemStock SET AMT='$dataReadyToImport' WHERE NAME='$itemID'");

    @mysql_close($HighCharts);

}

?>
```

Comment: Does PHP freeze or die because the (default) maximum execution time of 30 seconds has passed?

Comment: Well it stops even faster than 30 seconds but says it extendet it.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You don't have to open and close a connection for every query - open one connection to each server and make multiple `mysql_query()` calls to them.  That should speed you up quite a bit.

(2) Don't use "SELECT * FROM BetterShopItemStock" ... only select the row you need. (here, 'NAME').  And if you are already querying that table for 'NAME', then select 'AMT' at the same time, rather than making a second call to it.

(3) You can combine your select and update calls to HighCharts into a single query.

Altogether, everything should look something like this:

```
<?php

    //fiveMin - Database that data is taken form
    $fiveMin=mysql_connect($fiveMin_host,$fiveMin_user,$fiveMin_pass);
    mysql_select_db($fiveMin_db,$fiveMin) or die (mysql_error());

    //HighCharts - Database that data is transferred to
    $HighCharts=mysql_connect($week_host,$week_user,$week_pass); //Save stored data to weekly Database
    mysql_select_db($week_db,$HighCharts) or die (mysql_error());

    $query="SELECT NAME,AMT FROM BetterShopItemStock";
    $result = mysql_query($query,$fiveMin);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        collectData($row[0],$row[1],$HighCharts);
    }

    function collectData($itemID, $itemAmt, $mysql) {
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($itemID);
        $amt = mysql_real_escape_string($itemAmt);
        $q = "UPDATE BetterShopItemStock SET ".
             "AMT=CONCAT(AMT,',','$amt') WHERE NAME='$id'";
        $r = mysql_query($q,$mysql);
        return (!$r ? false : true);


    }

    //now close the databases
    @mysql_close($HighCharts);
    @mysql_close($fiveMin);
?>
```

(4) Lastly, if you are having execution timeout errors, look into PHP's [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) to extend your execution time

Comment: Excuce me but where you've got multiple mySqlquery here? And why you are changing my methods? I was appending data from one DB to another. `function collectData($itemID, $itemAmt, $mysql)` - this is sick. Why I have to incude $itemAmt and $mysql?

Comment: including `$itemAmt` prevents you from having to make a second `SELECT` call to get the `AMT` column.  And `$mysql` is just the mysql connection to the database that you will be updating (here, `$HighCharts`)

Answer (score 0):

Separate each one into classes and work with them after.  It makes them run more efficiently and the querys do not intermesh:

```
<?php
class class1{
     function fivemin(){
          **code0**
     }
     function collectdata1-fivemin() {
          class1::fivemin();
          **code**
     }
     function collectdataHighcharts(){
          class1::fivemin();
          **code2**
     }
}
$a = new class1;
$a->collectdata1-fivemin();
$a->collectdata1HighCharts();
?>
```

Comment: What `$a->collectdata1-fivemin();` does?